# Android: Async Task on CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a button on my activity that starts a notification and then also starts a Countdown Timer with an Async Task.  The purpose of the code is to convert the `millisUntilFinished` to readable time and send it to my GUI in the second activityI get this fatal exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
              Process: com.idkbro.pashchallenge, PID: 25702
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
                  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                  at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.<init>(CountDownTimer.java:114)
                  at android.os.CountDownTimer.<init>(CountDownTimer.java:114)
                  at com.idkbro.pashchallenge.MainActivity$1CDTTask$1.<init>(MainActivity.java:0)
                  at com.idkbro.pashchallenge.MainActivity$1CDTTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:250)
                  at com.idkbro.pashchallenge.MainActivity$1CDTTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:196)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946228/java-lang-runtimeexception-an-error-occured-while-executing-doinbackground) they said the error could be because of trying to update the GUI in the asynctask, but this isnt in my case because í send variable to the activity using an intent service. I think the problem could be how i "set up" my asynctask

The MainActivity class when the accept button is(P.S: so sorry about the code if its a but messy :(  ):

```
public void agreeButton (View v){



    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CountdownPage.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuiler  = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Pash Challenge")
            .setContentText("You have so many minutes left")//TODO make notification display countdown
            .setTicker("Alert new message")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pashicon);//Code to display notification


    Intent moreInfoIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MoreInfoNotification.class);


    notificationManager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(notificationID,notificationBuiler.build());


    // Used to stack tasks across activites so we go to the proper place when back is clicked
    TaskStackBuilder tStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

    // Add all parents of this activity to the stack
    tStackBuilder.addParentStack(MoreInfoNotification.class);

    // Add our new Intent to the stack
    tStackBuilder.addNextIntent(moreInfoIntent);

    // Define an Intent and an action to perform with it by another application
    // FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT : If the intent exists keep it but update it if needed
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = tStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Defines the Intent to fire when the notification is clicked
    notificationBuiler.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    isNotificationActive =true;


     class CDTTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{


         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {



             Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
             Long preTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();



             calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);// set milliseconds for 2 days
             Long postTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
             Long delay = postTime - preTime;

             AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)     getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
             manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, postTime, null);

             CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(delay, 1) {

                 @Override
                 public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished) {

                     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                         @Override
                         public void run() {

                             //SendAndCovert milliseconds to CoundownPage
                             SAndCDays(millisUntilFinished);
                             SAndCHours(millisUntilFinished);
                             SAndCMinutes(millisUntilFinished);
                             SAndCSeconds(millisUntilFinished);

                         }//End run
                     });//End runOnUiThread
                 }//End onTick

                 @Override
                 public void onFinish() {


                 }//End OnFinish
                  void SAndCDays(Long milli){ //Code to convert milliseconds to days and send it to CountdownPage.java

                     Long millis =  (milli / (1000*60*60*24));
                     String days = ""+millis;
                     Intent numIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CountdownPage.class);
                     numIntent.putExtra("days", days);
                     startActivity(numIntent);

                 }//End SAndCDays

                 void SAndCMinutes(Long milli){ //Code to convert milliseconds to minutes and send it to CountdownPage.java

                     long millis =  ((milli / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                     String minutes = ""+millis;
                     Intent numIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CountdownPage.class);
                     numIntent.putExtra("minutes", minutes);
                     startActivity(numIntent);

                 }//End SAndCMinutes
                 //Code to convert milliseconds to hours and send it to CountdownPage.java
                  void SAndCHours(Long milli){

                     long millis = (milli/ (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
                     String hours = ""+millis;
                     Intent numIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CountdownPage.class);
                     numIntent.putExtra("hours", hours);
                     startActivity(numIntent);

                 }//End SAndCHours
                    //Code to convert milliseconds to seconds and send it to CountdownPage.java
                  void SAndCSeconds(Long milli){

                     long millis = (milli/ 1000) % 60;
                     String seconds = ""+millis;
                     Intent numIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CountdownPage.class);
                     numIntent.putExtra("seconds", seconds);
                     startActivity(numIntent);

                 } //End SAndCSeconds
             };
             timer.start();
             return null;
         }//End doInBackground
     }
    CDTTask object = new CDTTask();
    object.execute();//Code to start Countdown Async task

} // End agreeButton
```

Here is my Alert Receiver class if its of any help:

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    createNotification(context, "Times Up", " x Seconds has past","alert");// TODO change to CDT Time


}//End onReceive

public void createNotification(Context context, String msg,
                               String txtMsg,String msgAlert) {

    PendingIntent notificIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    // Builds a notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pashicon)
                    .setContentTitle(msg)
                    .setTicker(msgAlert)
                    .setContentText(txtMsg);


    mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);



}//End createNotification
```

}//End AlertReceiver.class

And how i receive and display the coveted times from the service:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_challenge_page);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    TextView txtTimerDay=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTimerDay);
    TextView txtTimerMinute=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTimerMinute);
    TextView txtTimerHour=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTimerHour);
    TextView txtTimerSecond=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTimerSecond);


    txtTimerDay.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("days"));
    txtTimerMinute.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("minutes"));
    txtTimerHour.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("hours"));
    txtTimerSecond.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("seconds"));


}
```

Comment: Welcome, please create a [mcve] of this problem, this contains unecessary logic. This will be easier to debug and will gain in attention here ;)

Comment: Timer with Async Task doesn't work properly, you can use here Handler